# Looking for data on theatres of the world

Tags: data-request, geospatial

The data should contain:

- country
- name
- postal code
- town
- website

I found http://www.theatredb.com/, but it stopped to work in 2002, all data is outdated.

Comment: Based on link you provided ... I assume that you're looking for live theatre, not movie theatres.